# Mathematica ItemStyle -> Bolding with Grid

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am very near the end of my project but I cannot get one last thing to work out. I need to bold a few lines in my "grid" but I am not sure how. So far I am only able to get the top row and the last column to become bold. But i need rows 1,12,13,14, and 15 to be bolded and the last column to be bolded. I have uploaded a screen shot of what I currently have.

[What I currently have so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSUva.png)

as you can see only the top row and the last column are bolded. I reiterate I need the top row, and rows 12,13,14,15 to be bolded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a look at the specifications for `ItemStyle` in `Grid`'s *[Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html)* section of the documentation.

You have `ItemStyle->{-1-> Bold, 1-> Bold}` that is asking for the last column and the first row to be bold.  You want to skip specifying the columns and only specify the row so you have to tell it to use `Automatic` styling for the columns and then specify the row styling.

`ItemStyle->{{Automatic}, {12-> Bold, 13-> Bold, 14-> Bold, 15-> Bold}}`

Hope this helps.